# Strip all comments and create a new file with only (JS) code

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code hasn't been tested exhaustively - I would love suggestions about a testing library.

Critical, Optional and Positive feedback are more then welcome.

```
const fs = require('fs');

/**
 * strip all comments and create a new file with only code
 * @param {int} file name to clean..
 * @return {int} function returns 0 at the end.
 */
function clean(file) {
  const inputFileName = file;

  // create output file name. e.g: test.js -> test_CLEAN.js
  let outputFileName = inputFileName.split('.');
  outputFileName[0] += '_CLEAN';
  outputFileName = outputFileName.join('.');

  // clean output file old data
  fs.writeFile(outputFileName, ``, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  });

  // comments regex defentions
  // lines starts with // where // can have spaces before for indentation
  const singleLineComment = /^\s*\/\//;
  // start skipping lines on /* can have spaces before
  const multiLineCommentStart = /^\s*\/\*/;
  // stop skipping lines on */ end the end of the line
  const multiLineCommentEnd = /\*\/$/;
  // mixed lines with code and inline comments
  const singleLineCommentAfterCode = /[;]\s*\/\//;


  // skip lines bool
  let skipLine = false;

  // load input file to memory, split it by lines, filter white space lines, then loop over each line
  fs.readFileSync(inputFileName, 'utf-8')
      .split(/\n/)
      .filter((line) => line != '')
      .forEach((line) => {
        // return in a forEach() callback is equivalent to continue in a conventional for loop.

        if (multiLineCommentStart.test(line)) {
          skipLine = true;
          return;
        }

        if (multiLineCommentEnd.test(line)) {
          skipLine = false;
          return;
        }

        if (singleLineComment.test(line)) {
          return;
        }

        if (singleLineCommentAfterCode.test(line)) {
          line = line.split(' //')[0];
        }

        // append lines to output file
        if (!skipLine) {
          // append additional \n at the end of a blocks (after '};')
          line = line === '};' ? line + '\n' : line;
          fs.appendFileSync(outputFileName, `${line}\n`, (err) => {
            if (err) {
              // append failed
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
        }
      });

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You haven't even tested it?  Don't you think it's rude to ask for a review before you've done at least the basics?

Comment: not sure what you mean, the code works.. what's the problem?

Comment: If you haven't tested it, how do you know that the code works?

Comment: I've tested it manually with some files with JS code and some comments.

Comment: also, hostile work environment..

Comment: Ah, so you have tested it, then?  Just that your tests aren't as thorough as you'd like?  That's different.

Comment: ho, I see what you did there with the edit. makes much more sense that way :D

Comment: I wouldn't try to achieve such a task by hand, there will always be edge cases you won't catch (as the current answer shows). I've played around with a AST parser called "acorn" before - take a look at that. By default it doesn't store comments when it creates an AST tree, so theoritically it should be as simple as turnings the code into an AST tree and back.

Comment: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To handle codes, use a parser. Build an AST from parser (maybe comments are already removed there). And then convert it to codes. A FSM implementation *may* work. (I'm not sure). But I believe your current RegExp approach are far from working.

Anyway,

### 1. Line break

JavaScript support 5 different [line terminator sequence](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#prod-LineTerminatorSequence). Your code only support one or two of them.

### 2. Single line comment

Line end no need to have `;`.

```javascript
var a = 42// comment
```

#### 3. Multi line comment

Start / end of multi line comment no need to take a single line. They may appear on the same line.

```javascript
var a = 42; /* comment */
```

```javascript
var a = 42; /*
*/ var b = 42;
```

### 3. Some more complex comments

After you fix above issues, you are ready to handle more complex situations:

```javascript
var a = 3
/*
*// 3;
/*/ /*/
/* // */
// /*
var b = 4;
// */
```

### 4. String and RegExp

Text in strings / regular expressions are not comments.

```javascript
var a = '; // ';
```

```javascript
var a = '\
// ';
```

```javascript
var a = `
// `;
```

```javascript
var a = /[; //]/;
```

This would be more complex if mix them up.

```javascript
var c = `; // ${function () {
    a =  '}';
    // Wow, SO failed to use correct syntax highlight for this too!
}}`
```

### 5. HTML like comments

This could be optional. Most browsers supports HTML like comments. But this is not required to every JavaScript engine.

```javascript
var a = 42;
--> this is comment
<!-- this is comment too
```

### 6. Shebang

It is up to you if you want to handle shebang as comments. They work on some browsers.

```javascript
#!/usr/bin/node

var a = 42;
```

Comment: Thank you tsh, it gave me some things to think about.